# Running the GUI from another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created my GUI in a class "ClientGUI.java" and tried to create an instance in another class ("Client.java"). The GUI simply consists of two buttons ("Forward" and "Backward") of which only one button is present at a time. 
At first the GUI seems to work fine as the frame is displayed with one button. However once the button is pushed it just disappears and is not replaced by the second one.
By setting breakpoints I found out that the correct ActionListener function is called and the first button removed but not the second one added.

The GUI class "ClientGUI.java":

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClientGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JButton btnForward = new JButton("Forward"),
            btnBackward = new JButton("Backward");

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ClientGUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(btnForward, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnForward.addActionListener(this);
        btnBackward.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        if (e.getSource() == btnForward) {
            remove(btnForward);

            add(btnBackward, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == btnBackward) {
            remove(btnBackward);

            add(btnForward);

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClientGUI");

        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ClientGUI());

        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the class "Clients.java" from which i want to use the GUI:

```
import java.net.*;
import GUI.ClientGUI;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
    }

    Client() {
        String[] args = {"ggg", "vvv"};

            try {
                new ClientGUI().main(args);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `init`. from another class. You should call it from the constructor. In your case it may not work though, since your class in a JPanel that you add to to the frame in `init`, so if you call `init` from the contructor, you'll get an infinite loop. See my answer. I just made some simple fixes. But there is still more you can improve on - in terms of good practice.

Comment: @mKorbel I was thinking the same thing to, but the OP isn't trying to use two sepearate frames. The question makes it seem like that, but the OP is just trying to run the GUI class from another class that loads the GUI.

Comment: @peeskillet can be good point/catch, but without OPs reaction ........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't ever call the `main` method. The `main` method is for the JVM to know the entry point for the program.
2. Don't use two `main` methods. Whichever is the entry point program, have the `main` method only in that one
3. Just use a constructor. When the first GUI calls the second one, everything in the constructor will be constructed.

Here's a revamped version. It works.

- I got rid of the `main` from `ClientGUI`
- I called `ClientGUI.createAndShowGUI()` from the `main` in the `Client` class.

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Client();
            }
        });
    }

    Client() {
        String[] args = {"ggg", "vvv"};

        try {
            ClientGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ClientGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JButton btnForward = new JButton("Forward"),
            btnBackward = new JButton("Backward");



    public ClientGUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(btnForward, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnForward.addActionListener(this);
        btnBackward.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnForward) {
            remove(btnForward);

            add(btnBackward, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnBackward) {
            remove(btnBackward);

            add(btnForward);

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClientGUI");

        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ClientGUI());

        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for explanation and code example!
I assume SwingUtilities.invokeLater is called inside the main method of the client class ?

Comment: Yeah I accidently deleted the `main` when I added the SwingUtilities. **Fixed**

Comment: Thanks again for your fast response. All the bad practices aside i believe the main problem was "new ClientGUI().main(args);". If that line instead was "ClientGUI.main(args);" (or the CreateAndShow method) it would already work. Could you please explain what exactly is the problem with creating a ClientGUI object there ?

Comment: The problem is that your `ClientGUI` is a `JPanel` in itself. So if you just instantiate it, it does nothing because a `JPanel` need a parent container. So instantiating it is useless in your case. The I did it was _not_ to instantiate it, but rather statically call its `createAndShowGUI` because that is the method with the `JFrame` that adds the class `JPanel` to it.

Comment: And also like I said, you **never** want to call the `main` method. The JVM does that for you. And you should **never** have two `main` methods. So your idea about all you needed to do was `ClientGUI.main(args);`, just erase that thought ever being in your head :)

Comment: Ok. Already erased :) . Thank you again for your explanation. I believe that cleared it all up!